# Как запускать функцию через интервал времени?

Tags: php, javascript

Есть функция на php, допустим:

```
function pop($num) {
    //.....
}
```

Как мне ее запускать через определенный интервал времени? Есть на php аналог js функции setTimeout?

Comment: Опишите точнее задачу. Если это не тот случай, когда можно/нужно вызвать PHP-скрипт по асинхронному запросу из JS, то скорее всего подойдет какой-нибудь планировщик типа cron. Проводить аналогии между JS и PHP в этом отношении некорректно - два разных языка с разными задачами и разным окружением.

Answer (score 3):

не получится у вас как в JS. Вам нада тут пользоватся [Cron](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron)

Answer (score 2):

нельзя. Нет в PHP аналога setTimeout.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы сделал это так.

Присвоил переменую функции **date(i)**, указал формат,а потом сравнил с условием(например минуты),если оно верно,выполнялась бы функция.

**P.S** При этом страница должна перезагружаться каждый раз.

Поэтому...

...А вообще лучше использовать JS.

Comment: А как можно совместить js таймер и php код?

Answer (score -1):

В PHP есть такая прекрасная функция как [**`sleep`**](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.sleep.php).

Comment: Тоесть я теперь делаю так:

function pop($num) { 

 //..... 
 sleep(2);
 pop($num);

}

Правильно?
Но не работает..

Comment: Если делать даже без попыток понять, что произойдет при попытке выполнить код - и не заработает)

Comment: Тогда уж
    
function pop($num) {
    // тело функции
    return $continue; // продолжать?
}
while(pop(get_mystic_value())) { // show must go on
    sleep(1);
}

Comment: sleep() - дурь =)

Comment: Спасибо ребят. Да все получилось. Просто думал она будет по другому работать)

Comment: бред
вы разницу между sleep - задержка выполнениея скрипта и setTimeout - задание интервала между запуском функции понимаете?

Answer (score -1):

здесь нужно воспользоваться заголовком header

```
<?php
header('Refresh:1');

echo date('d-m-Y H:m:s');
?>
```

типа часики получаются, но и вся страница будет обновляться